# junit test for javafx sample login form

Tags: javafx, junit4

please help to test this code using junit

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
    scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
    grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

    Label pw = new Label("Password:");
    grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

    PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
    grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);

  Label  status = new Label();
    status.setId( "status-label" );

    Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
    btn.setId("btn");
    HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
    hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
    grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);
    grid.add(status, 1, 8);



    final Text actiontarget = new Text();
    grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);
   // ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("person.png"), 0, 65, true, true));
    //grid.add(imageView, 0, 0,2,2);   

    //btn.setOnAction( ( e ) -> status.setText( computeStatus() ) );
    //private String computeStatus() {
    //  return "Name: " + userTextField.getText() + ", Password: " + pwBox.getText();
    //}
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            actiontarget.setFill(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
            actiontarget.setText("Name: " + userTextField.getText() + ", Password: " + pwBox.getText());

        }
    });


    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [MarvinFX](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/03/introducing-marvinfx/) or [TestFX](https://github.com/SmartBear/TestFX) or [JemmyFX](http://java.net/projects/jemmy/sources/jemmy3/show)

Comment: @hotzst....thanks for your reply,i would like to know how to test the login using JUnit4..i have gone through few basic examples but have no idea of testing the sample login form...Thanks in advance

Comment: As you are testing a UI here, JUnit on it's own is not enough. For that reason you need one of the mentioned frameworks, which build upon JUnit.